# Oracle Sql developer: Not showing source code of views, triggers, functions for Oracle RDB

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-rdb

I am using Oracle Sql developer to access my Oracle RDB database. I have installed Oracle RDB extension for Sql developer.

I see there everything in object browser - tables, views, triggers, functions, procedures.

The problem is **When i want to see source code of any of views, triggers and function/procedures by mouse double-click, Sql developer does not show source code, it does not show any error**

Does anybody have any idea how to retrieve or see source code of those views, triggers and functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you double-clicking to bring this up for non-RDB Oracle? I cannot duplicate bringing up the source code of a table/view if I double-click on the name in a query or in the connections pane.

Comment: I double click( and many other combinations of key and mouse ) on a particular view on connections pane under view folder. But not showing source code for Oracle RDB, but when i  use the same way for normal Oracle database, the source code was shown.

Comment: If I double-click (or single-click) on a view in the connections pane in SQL Developer 4.1.0.19 it brings up the columns view and I have to manually select the SQL tabbed-pane - so I cannot duplicate the behavior you are seeing for a normal Oracle database. For functions, procedures and triggers the default view is the source code (but then they don't have underlying data or columns so that would not make sense for them).

Comment: The problem is that this bring up source code or column details is not working for oracle RDB. I do have sql developer version 4.1.3.20

Comment: I have found a directiion how to do it by setting user defined extensions for sql developer like this:                                                                               <items> 
<item type="editor" node="ViewNode" vertical="true"> 
<title><![CDATA[Triggers - Custom]]></title> 
<query> 
<sql><![CDATA[SELECT rdb$trigger_name, rdb$trigger_type,
rdb$trigger_source as source
FROM rdb$triggers 
where rdb$trigger_name = :OBJECT_NAME 
ORDER BY rdb$trigger_name]]></sql> 
</query> 
</item> 
</items>

Comment: Rather than putting it in a comment, if it is a solution to your problem then put it in an answer and accept that answer. There is nothing wrong with self-answered questions (in fact, if it is a good question then it is encouraged as it adds value to the site).

Answer (score 0):

*This is the method for details for an Oracle database in SQL Developer (it may be the same for the RDB extension but I cannot verify this - if it is not then I hope this will be valuable to someone looking for the answer for a pure-Oracle perspective).*

To see the SQL for a `VIEW`:

1. In the connections pane, expand the connection.
2. Expand the Views sub-folder.
3. Click on the View you want details of.
4. In the main panel, this should now show details of the columns of the view.
5. At the top of the main panel are a series of tabbed panes; the right-most one is "SQL" and if you click on it then it will show the SQL for the view.

For `TRIGGER`, `FUNCTION`, `PROCEDURE` or most other objects, the method is the same just select the appropriate object type instead of `VIEW` but the default action at step 4 will be to show the source code for that object.

Comment: Hi, I see the all views and the others on object browser, i have no problem with it, but the problem is i can not see source code of the view or the others, usually source code is prompt when you click mouse double click for oracle, but looks like Oracle rdb is not the same. I tried many other combinations of keys not no luck.